# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined - React Native

Tags: react-native, reactjs, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

## Question

Why am I getting this error when I click on the navigation button?

## My code

```
render() {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation

  var listOfPools = this.state.myValue;
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < listOfPools.length; i++) {
      console.log(listOfPools[i].name);
      output.push(
        <Button
              onPress={() => navigate('DisplayPools', { name: listOfPools[i].name + 'name',  list: listOfPools[i].imageSrcList } ) }
              title={listOfPools[i].name + ' - ' + i}
              key={i}
        />
      );
  }

  return (
       //works
       <Button
           onPress={() => navigate('DisplayPools', { name: this.state.myValue[0].name,  list: this.state.myValue[0].imageSrcList} ) }
           title={this.state.myValue[0].name}
        />
      //does not work (when I click the button that appears, it displays the buttons perfectly)
      <ScrollView>{output}</ScrollView>
  )
}
```

## What happens

It outputs all of the buttons, with the correct names (showing that `this.state.myValue` is defined). Then when I click on the buttons it gives me the error below.

## What should happen

It should display the names of the buttons (it does) and direct me to the DisplayPools page (it does in the `//working` code but not in the `{output}` code).

## Error

[image]

#### Line 160 (Where the error occurred)

```
onPress={() => navigate('DisplayPools', { name: listOfPools[i].name + 'name',  list: listOfPools[i].imageSrcList } ) }
```

## What I am trying to accomplish

I would like to send data from my server to my app. Then I would like to have my app display links from the data that my server gave it.

## How I load the data

#### I do not think that this is relevant, but here it is anyway:

```
loadData() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/home')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseText) => {
      this.setState({ myValue: responseText.pools, loaded: true, });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({ myValues: error, loaded: true, });
    });
  }
```

and

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }
```

Comment: it's pointing out that `this.state.myValue` is undefined, try logging it or the result of the `loadData` method to see if you're getting the correct data that you are expecting.

Comment: I have tried that, it outputs exactly what it should. I also know that it is not undefined, because the buttons show up properly with the correct name. (I will clarify this)

Comment: i see. can you include the line number 160 of your code from index.ios?

Comment: it is the `onPress` line, I just updated it above. Here is the git repo it is on, sorry about the messy code. https://github.com/pudility/fireClient

Comment: If you have a better way to do this (output an unknown number of buttons with unique names) that does not provide the error, I would be just as happy with that

Comment: I tried replicating the issue with your code, took me a while to figure it out but i think there's a difference with the behavior between the `for` loop and the `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it with `map` function,it worked, try this:

```
listOfPools.map((data, i) => (
      output.push(
        <Button
              onPress={() => navigate('DisplayPools', { name: data.name + 'name',  list: [] } ) }
              title = {data.name}
              key={i}
        />
      )
    ));
```

You'll still encounter problems with your `imageSource`. It seems you have not set the initial state.